# KV Language Rectangle self.size Does Not Work

Tags: python, canvas, kivy, kivy-language

I'm having trouble displaying a properly sized canvas that only consists of a red rectangle, and I want to fill the rectangle up to the "size" of the canvas. The position works, but the size does not, as follows:
[image: The size is too big]

While I'm expecting something more like this:
[image: A much smaller rectangle]

Here's my code:
my.kv:

```
<MyWidget>
    pos: 100, 100
    size: 64, 64
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: 1, 0, 0
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
```

And MyApp.py:

```
class MyWidget(Widget):
    pass

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyWidget()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

I've tried setting the pos and size properties directly for the rectangle, but then I realized I couldn't manipulate it dynamically afterwards, so that's not what I needed. And I thought that `pos` and `size` under `<MyWidget>` would act as variables that can be accessed through `self`. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `size_hint: None, None` as well as just `size`, otherwise the size hint takes precedence.

Comment: Ah that worked, thanks! It just doesn't feel very intuitive, though, with the way they named these properties (hint?) and also how `pos_hint` doesn't seem to take precedence.